# Не нажимается Enter

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, chromedriver

Этот же код работает в jupyter, но не в pycharm. В поисковой строке появляется вводимое слово, но сам Enter не нажимается, уже многое перепробовал

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://ruz.hse.ru/ruz/main")
name=chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/ruz-root/div/ruz-main-index/ruz-list/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/p-autocomplete/span/input')
name.click()
name.send_keys("БИТ212")
name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

В Jupyter не пробовал, но запуск в терминале у меня фейлится так же как и PyCharm - не похоже на баг IDE.

Вот такое наивное изменение решило проблему в моем случае

```py
...
name.send_keys("БИТ212")
time.sleep(1)
name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(100)
```

Кажется frontend не успевает за Selenium. По науке нужно видимо добавить wait вместо sleep.